# Magento 2 : Change Order # Formatting for M2 Orders

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am trying to implement feature that Orders placed on M2 should start with a ' 3 ' instead of a ' 2 '

This will help me with easily identifying new orders while we move test orders to production and for post live tracking.

What would be the most convenient method to do so programmatically, following by best practice ?

Comment: any thoughts would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from the table `sales_sequence_profile` by changing value of `prefix` column for the particular `meta_id`

You will find order `meta_id` from `sales_sequence_meta` this table based on your store view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have opened & checked tables.
This is it ? Everything else would be managed automatically by magento if i change prefix for a store's meta id ?

Comment: Also i would like to ask if it can be done programmatically ?

Comment: yes after changing value in table it will work. I don't know about the code. till now I have done with the db only

Comment: ok rakesh thanks for the answer, i have to perform this programmatically, so i need to check that.

Comment: once you get the solution using programmatically post it in your question so it will helpful for other as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your database
2. Find & click on the table called: sequence_order_1
3. Change "AUTO_INCREMENT" edit to desired order number. like 30000526

This should work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, That's it ? Everything else would be managed automatically by magento ?
For credit memo, invoice, shipment ?

Comment: Also would like to ask if it will work for multiple stores ?

Comment: For multiple stores you will find multiple sequences like _1, _2 etc

Comment: For invoice shipment, credit memo you have other tables like this. sequence_creditmemo_0, sequence_creditmemo_1, sequence_invoice_0, sequence_invoice_1 etc

Comment: ok so i need to change there in those table also ?

Comment: I'ts up to you, if you need to change credit memo id, then update it's sequence, and other tables likewise. for just order numbers you need to update sequence_order_1

Comment: I don't to change credit memo id , just want to change order id.
changing just order id will managed everywhere in magento like
credit memo invoice shipment etc?

Comment: Change "AUTO_INCREMENT" edit to desired order number. like 30000526

- I am trying to add prefix to the order id's you answer will work for that ?

Comment: If you need just number as prefix, then you just need to change auto_increment otherwise see other answer of Rakesh Varma

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer at https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/change-order-prfix-increment-id-suffix-invoice.html
I hope you find this helpful!